# Can you split a set into equal parts?

Tags: python, set, slice

I want to do something like the following:

```
s = set()
s.add('a')
s.add('q')
s.add('x')
s.add('banana')

s1 = s(:1)
s2 = s(2:3)
```

Is the above a valid operation on sets? Is there a way to apply the above to a generator such as:

```
def Chunks(container, size):
    for i in xrange(0, len(container), size):
        yield container(i:i+size)
```

Comment: sets don't have `append` method and they are not sequences, so subscription is not possible.

Comment: They have an `add` method.

Comment: They do have `add`, though. Unfortunately, they can't be indexed, because they're unordered.

Comment: Hmm, ok - I wonder if there's a way to cast it as a list? I don't actually care about the order of the items, I just want to split it into equal parts.

Comment: Of course you can do `list(my_set)`

Comment: Ultimately I think the question is how often do you need to do this, how much do you care about benchmarks (Do you need only a set or an *ordered set*)? If I needed to make the slice often I'd write a short wrapper for an ordered set, if I cared about benchmarks I'd install a package or implement the structure in C with a python wrapper to have the exact lookup properties / benchmarks that are necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the set to a list, do the slicing, and then convert it back to sets:

```
In [13]: s = {1,2,3}

In [14]: s_l = list(s)

In [15]: print set(s_l[:1]), set(s_l[1:])
set([1]) set([2, 3])
```

Do note that sets do not support ordering, so any such ordering operation would have to be done within a list:

```
In [16]: s = {1,2,3,0}

In [17]: s
Out[17]: {0, 1, 2, 3}

In [18]: s_l = list(s)

In [19]: print set(s_l[:2]), set(s_l[2:])
set([0, 1]) set([2, 3])
```

Answer (score 3):

Sets are not indexable in the same way that lists are, but you can iterate over "chunks" or subgroups from them. Use the `grouper` recipe from `itertools`:

```py
from itertools import izip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

s2 = set('Andy Sandy Jack Jill Frank Fred Sally Sarah Bill Billy Bob'.split())

for g in grouper(s2, 3):
    print g
```

Yields:

```py
('Sarah', 'Frank', 'Bill')
('Fred', 'Billy', 'Jill')
('Andy', 'Jack', 'Bob')
('Sally', 'Sandy', None)
```

The initial order of the set initializer is not preserved because unlike lists, 
sets don't preserve order.

Answer (score 3):

Using `itertools.islice` it would be easy

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> def chunk(it, size):
...    it = iter(it)
...    return iter(lambda: tuple(islice(it, size)), ())

>>> data = {i for i in range(20)}

for j in chunk({i for i in range(20)}, 4):
...     print(j)
... 
(0, 1, 2, 3)
(4, 5, 6, 7)
(8, 9, 10, 11)
(12, 13, 14, 15)
(16, 17, 18, 19)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice), though sets don't guarantee an ordering so be careful if you aren't looking at the whole set

Comment: No you can't, unless you know of a way to get the other half of the slice in guaranteed order.

Comment: @user3467349 I thought that the order of elements within a set doesn't change once the set is constructed, so you should be able to do that with islice, right?

Comment: @mu無 Yes, I guess that's true, you have to be careful but it will work if you create and use both generators without modifying the set.